# What's the point of Guava checkNotNull

Tags: java, null, guava, preconditions

I'm pretty new to Guava (let's be honest, I'm not "pretty new", I'm a complete rookie on that subject) and so I decided to go through some documentation and got quite amazed while reading this:

[`com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(...)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull-T-)

I don't get the point of this method.
This means that instead of doing :

```
myObject.getAnything();
```

*(which might cause a `NullPointerException` if myObject is null)*

I should use

```
checkNotNull(myObject).getAnything();
```

which **will** throw a `NullPointerException` if `myObject` is null and return `myObject` if it is not null.

I'm puzzled and this might be the stupidest question ever but ...

What is the point of this?
Those two lines do the exact same thing as for outcomes given any situations I can think of.

I don't even think that the latter is more readable.

So I must be missing something. What is it?

Comment: I don't really buy in the idea of adding checkNotNull at every place. IMHO, it'd be more preferable if you verify your input explicitly, instead of over-relying on the syntactic sugar that help obfuscate your code. Fail fast is OK, but checkNotNull just doesn't give any other info for troubleshooting --> you can simply make your own exception for wrong input format, and put in a nice message explaining the specific situation

Comment: I totally agree this is ridiculous. Checking for null and then throwing an NPE yourself is, in my humble opinion totally nuts. At least throw a ValidationException or IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Consider providing better diagnostics with `checkNotNull(reference, errorMessageTemplate, errorMessageArgs)`: https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull-T-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The idea is to fail fast. For instance, consider this silly class:

```
public class Foo {
    private final String s;

    public Foo(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public int getStringLength() {
        return s.length();
    }
}
```

Let's say you don't want to allow null values for `s`. (or else `getStringLength` will throw a NPE). With the class as-is, by the time you catch that `null`, it's too late -- it's very hard to find out who put it there. The culprit could well be in a totally different class, and that `Foo` instance could have been constructed a long time ago. Now you have to comb over your code base to find out who could possibly have put a `null` value there.

Instead, imagine this constructor:

```
public Foo(String s) {
    this.s = checkNotNull(s);
}
```

Now, if someone puts a `null` in there, you'll find out *right away* -- and you'll have the stack trace pointing you exactly to the call that went wrong.

---

Another time this can be useful is if you want to check the arguments before you take actions that can modify state. For instance, consider this class that computes the average of all string lengths it gets:

```
public class StringLengthAverager {
    private int stringsSeen;
    private int totalLengthSeen;

    public void accept(String s) {
        stringsSeen++;
        totalLengthSeen += s.length();
    }

    public double getAverageLength() {
        return ((double)totalLengthSeen) / stringsSeen;
    }
}
```

Calling `accept(null)` will cause an NPE to get thrown -- but not before `stringsSeen` has been incremented. This may not be what you want; as a user of the class, I may expect that if it doesn't accept nulls, then its state should be unchanged if you pass a null (in other words: the call should fail, but it shouldn't invalidate the object). Obviously, in this example you could also fix it by getting `s.length()` before incrementing `stringsSeen`, but you can see how for a longer and more involved method, it might be useful to first check that all of your arguments are valid, and only then modify state:

```
    public void accept(String s) {
        checkNotNull(s); // that is, s != null is a precondition of the method

        stringsSeen++;
        totalLengthSeen += s.length();
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be more
this.s=Preconditions.checkNotNull(s);

Comment: but yeah I did not think about the storing case.

Comment: The typical pattern is `this.s = checkNotNull(s);` with a static import.

Comment: @Ar3s I added another use case.

Comment: Personally I think this kind of error reporting should be avoided. Whatever trick you do, a NullPointerException literally has little to no meaning. I'm strongly against passing/returning null in ANY function (unless you're working with legacy API), therefore any effort to do so should get a WrongApiUsage exception into the face.

Comment: @HoàngLong I also wish that `checkNotNull` would throw an IllegalArgumentException, instead of NPE. To me, an NPE means that someone tried to dereference a null pointer -- not that someone caught the fact that it was null before they tried to dereference it. But with that said, I also think that "IllegalArgumentException: foo was null" isn't more helpful than "NullPointerException: foo" in any practical sense. So, while I kinda wish that the Guava folks had picked IllegalArgumentException, the convenience and standardization of `checkNotNull` override that nit, at least for me.

Comment: @yshavit if you want an IllegalArgumentException, you can use `checkArgument` instead of `checkNotNull`.  `checkNotNull` has a "good enough" meaning if you use the implementation with a string explanation.  It's intended to be a safeguard, not a logical check.

Answer (score 10):

> `myObject.getAnything();` (which might cause a NullPointerException if myObject is null)

No... it *will* throw NPE whenever `myObject == null`. In Java, there's no chance of calling a method with `null` receiver (a theoretical exception are static methods, but they can and should be always called without any object).

---

> I should use `checkNotNull(myObject).getAnything();`

No you should not. This would be rather redundant (**Update**).

You should use `checkNotNull` in order to *fail fast*. Without it, you may pass an illegal `null` to another method, which passes it further, and so on and so on, where it finally fails. Then you can need some good luck to find out that actually the very first method should have refused `null`.

---

The answer by yshavit mentions an important point: Passing an illegal value is bad, but storing it and passing it later is even worse.

### Update

Actually,

```
 checkNotNull(myObject).getAnything()
```

makes sense, too, as you clearly express your intent to not accept any nulls. Without it, someone could think that you forgot the check and convert it into something like

```
 myObject != null ? myObject.getAnything() : somethingElse
```

OTOH, I don't think the check is worth the verbosity. In a [better language](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html), the type system would consider nullability and give us some semantic sugar like

```
 myObject!!.getAnything()                    // checkNotNull
 myObject?.getAnything()                     // safe call else null
 myObject?.getAnything() ?: somethingElse    // safe call else somethingElse
```

for nullable `myObject`, while the standard dot syntax would be allowed only when `myObject` is known to be non-null.

Comment: So that is like checking in the begin of a method that a precondition about the method is valid?

Comment: Exactly. Checking for illegal arguments immediately ensures you wan't have to hunt them down later. Moreover, everyone looking at the method sees what's forbidden (sure, it should be documented...).

Comment: @Juru: Yep, that's why it's in the `Preconditions` class!

Answer (score 6):

I have read this whole thread few minutes ago. Nevertheless I was confused why should we use `checkNotNull`. Then look over Precondition class doc of Guava and I got what I expected. Excessive use of `checkNotNull` will degrade performance definitely.

My thought is `checkNotNull` method is worth required for **data validation which comes from user directly** or very end API to user interaction. It shouldn't be used in each and every methods of internal API because using it you can't stop exception rather correct your internal API to avoid Exception.

**According to DOC:** [Link](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull(T))

> Using checkNotNull:

```
public static double sqrt(double value) {
     Preconditions.checkArgument(value >= 0.0, "negative value: %s", value);
     // calculate the square root
}
```

> **Warning about performance**
>
> The goal of this class is to improve readability of code, but in some
>   circumstances this may come at a significant performance cost.
>   Remember that parameter values for message construction must all be
>   computed eagerly, and autoboxing and varargs array creation may happen
>   as well, even when the precondition check then succeeds (as it should
>   almost always do in production). In some circumstances these wasted
>   CPU cycles and allocations can add up to a real problem.
>   Performance-sensitive precondition checks can always be converted to
>   the customary form:

```
if (value < 0.0) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("negative value: " + value);
}
```

Comment: Giving -1, sorry: I don't recommend using this for user data validation because you will want to give the user a more user-friendly non-technical error message. Also runtime exceptions are not intended in case the erratic situation can be expected to happen. A user can be expected to make a mistake now and then. I'd suggest checking method arguments in public methods but not in private methods. Catching programming errors earlier is worth more than premature optimization. Replace the Precondition check only when you find it to be an actual performance problem.

Comment: @HennoVermeulen As you said "checking method arguments in public methods" I also told "It shouldn't be used in each and every method of internal API". Thanks

Comment: Upvoted for the heads up on on performance, but as others have said, not a great approach to user validation!